# Is a PHP class destructor always called in the Apache HTTP request thread context?

Tags: php

I have PHP application (PHP 5.3) in which logging is done in a class destructor.

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function __destruct() {
    $string = ...
    $file = new SplFileObject('filename', 'a');
    $file->fwrite($string."\n");

}
```

There is only one server doing the logging.
Basically, the code doing the logging saves the current timestamp (end of request) along with other information such as duration ...

Strangely, when I look at the logs, the timestamps don't always appear in chronological order. I have difference of almost 2 minutes. For example (my logs):

```
2014-05-10 14:30:00 log1
2014-05-10 14:28:00 log2 (ended 2 minutes before previous log)
2014-05-10 14:30:01 log3
2014-05-10 14:30:02 log4
```

When I look at the Apache logs, my timestamp matches the Apache timestamp (except order).

```
2014-05-10 14:28:00 log2
...
2014-05-10 14:30:00 log1
2014-05-10 14:30:01 log3
2014-05-10 14:30:02 log4
```

The only explanation I can imagine is that destructor is not called by the HTTP thread but another thread at a later time. Can anyone confirm this or provide another (documented) explanation.

Comment: I don't think that.. Try adding some output on the destructor and see if you get it on the request body..

Comment: Someone mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#105368) that if an object refers to itself, it won't be removed from memory as we'd expect. Perhaps your objects aren't deconstructed until later because something is holding them in memory.

Comment: Off topic (somehow) using class destructors isn't an encouraged practice mostly because they are unpredictable, it is almost imposible to know exactly how the memory will unload an object and when.

Comment: `The working directory in the script shutdown phase can be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).`

Comment: Agree with SpiderLinked: Unless you are explicitly destroying the object, you really can't know how the environment is going to handle destruction. PHP stacks destruction calls in the order the object is in memory, which may not be in the order the object lost its references.

Comment: while what has been said in previous comments is correct, you can if you want to test this and you have a point in your flow where you are pretty sure your class should have been deconstructed, you can use garbage collector to shuffle the order and force deconstruct of the classes that are no longer in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test, if you destructor writes to file, by fetching the return value of fwrite(), like so

```
public function __destruct() {
    $string = ...
    $file = new SplFileObject('filename', 'a');
    $number_of_bytes = $file->fwrite($string."\n");
    echo "Wrote $number_of_bytes bytes to log file";
}
```

Sidenote: A destructor should not be used for new business logic, but for cleaning up allocated resources. I suggest you to use events/hooks for logging.

Plus something to consider: the PHP manual suggests to not use destructors for `session_write_close`. Instead they favor the usage of `register_shutdown_function()`.

This works always:

```
register_shutdown_function('log');

function log() {
    $string = ...
    $file = new SplFileObject('filename', 'a');
    $number_of_bytes = $file->fwrite($string."\n");
    echo "Wrote $number_of_bytes bytes to log file";
}
```

Comment: The destructor is always called. The thing I can't explain is why the logs do not contain sequential dates.

Comment: I think, the dates are not sequentially written, because there is no file locking. With Apache, locks are advisory only, so even if Apache gets an IO lock, the another process could just write the file. (This is also the case with session files.) Maybe `strace` is of help in figuring out, what happens.